# (Cycles) Transparent object casting shadow issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to make an animation of a fade in, but when using transparent shader, glass with 1 IOR, Alpha, anything casts shadow.
I just wanted to make the object disapear from the scene, and smothly apear in order.

Here is the evidence.

[image: shadow or ambient occlusion, I dunno]

[image]

Comment: transparent causes this issue, and holdout don't work with mixer, it makes the object invisible for good regardless of the factor.... But thanks, i didnt't know the holdout.

Comment: You can see in the image that the sole is casting shadow on the ground, I'll try to make 2 keys, 1 of render e another with the factor, to see if combined they work.

Comment: Is that transparent part intersect with the shoes itself? Maybe an wireframe screen shot can help to resolve the problem

Comment: That is the sole from inside the shoe, and the shader I was trying to apply changing the factor.

Comment: There will be two or more surface been saw from camera angle. This is not allow to use any surface transparent without some darken overlay. And you mesh is complicate also. I would probably render 2 frame and interpolate them directly rather than using a transparent material.

Comment: Well, now I know the reason, it's because of a AO node input in every material, I changed to world's AO, and it's fixed to some extend, when I have the full answer I'll share with you

Answer (score 2):

Two possibility in my mind:

**Object → Visibility → Ray visibility → Shadow** in the object properties panel. (set to unchecked)

[image]

**Material → Setting → surface → Transparent Shadow** in the object properties panel. (set to checked)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but withou any shadow, the final fade-in will not work. And the transparent shadow is already checked.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, know I get it.

What I was seeing was the texture AO and not a shadow, sorry guys.
What I did was:

1 - removed the AO + color ramp from my textures.

2 - changed the world configuration adding AO with the same AO configuration from my textures.

3 - 1 frame before the fade effect, I changed the object render from disable to enable, then it's lighter to process the scene.

Now it's working.
Thank you guys!
Just a test, I need to polish more, change some times and orders, and only then, render in Cycles.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1nfQLAX064

Comment: +1 for figuring it out ... it's not always such a quick process